# Inconsistency in a Z-transform of an Euler equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, z-transform

In [this thesis, p. 27,](http://www.r2labs.org/thesis/FinalStraderThesis.pdf) the following Euler equation is given, see (4.9):
$$
u_{i+1,j}=\frac{h_t}{2h_x^2}\left[\left(\frac{2h_x^2}{h_t}+2a_1h_x^2-4a_2\right)u_{i,j}+(2a_2-a_3h_x)u_{i,j-1}+(2a_2+a_3h_x)u_{i,j+1}+2b_1h_x^2\right]
$$

Here, $i$ represents the time and $j$ represents the (1d-) space. Moreover, $h_t$ and $h_x$ are the step sizes with respect to time and space, respectively. $a_1,a_2$ and $b_1$ are constants.

Then, on both sides, the z-tranformation (with respect to time) is applied, where
$$
\mathcal{Z}(u_{i+1,j})=:U_j,~\mathcal{Z}(u_{i,j})=z^{-1}U_j,~\mathcal{Z}(u_{i,j-1})=z^{-1}U_{j-1},~\mathcal{Z}(u_{i,j+1})=U_{j+1}.
$$

Due to the linked thesis, this gives (4.10)
$$
U_j=\frac{h_t}{2h_x^2}\left[\left(\frac{2h_x^2}{h_t}+2a_1h_x^2-4a_2\right)z^{-1}U_j+(2a_2-a_3h_x)z^{-1}U_{j-1}+(2a_2+a_3h_x)z^{-1}U_{j+1}+\color{blue}{2b_1h_x^2}\right]
$$

I am really wondering about the blue summand! Why isn't it
$$
\mathcal{Z}(2b_1h_x^2)=2b_1h_x^2\mathcal{Z}(1)?
$$

Is there some reason for that or is it just a mistake? I would really prefer that there is some reason for it. :-)

*In particular this seems relevant since the author is interested in poles and zeros $z$ of the z-transform with $\lvert z\rvert <1$ for stability reasons; but for $\lvert z\rvert <1$, we have that $\mathcal{Z}(1)$ diverges. Moreover, the determination of the zeros and poles does not work as done in the thesis in case the summand is $2b_1h_x^2\mathcal{Z}(1)$.*

Comment: Note; "Z transform" in control theory is what is called "Laurent series" in mathematics.

Comment: The Z-transform and the time shift are related by a factor of z. How come the shift in space is also related to a factor? i.e.: is the factor $z^{-1}$ correct in $\mathcal{Z}(u_{i,j-1})=z^{-1}U_{j-1}$ ?

Comment: @VictorZurkowski I think it is correct since with respect to time $i$ this is one shift back from $i+1$ to $i$. I guess this is meant as time shift and not as space shift; I cannot fully understand the notation with the space, too. I guess they just see it as a function of time and not of space.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation that you write, the Z-transform does indeed include the $\mathcal Z(1)$ term.

I think there should be a term with the initial condition $u_{0,j} $, because $\mathcal Z(u_{i,j}) = z^{-1}U_j + u_{0,j}$, but I digress.

Here is an idea to get rid of having to deal with $b_1$, at least in case $a_1 \ne 0$, because in that case, the constant function $v_{i,j} = -\frac{b_1}{a_1}$ satisfies the non-homogeneous equation, and so, $u-v$ satisfies the homogeneous equation (without $b_1$).

Comment: I do not think that there is the summand $u_{0,j}$ since it just one shift back in time.

Comment: According to the definition above, $U_j =\mathcal Z(u_{i+1,j}) $ is the transform of  $u_{1,j}, u_{2,j}, ...$, and it does not involve $u_{0,j}$. The transform of ${u_{i,j}}$ does involve $u_{0,j}$, so $u_{0,j}$ has to be included somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your point. Up to my understanding, it is just $Z(u_{i,j})=z^{-1}Z(u_{i+1,j})$ since we are going one time step backwards.

Comment: $\mathcal Z(u_{i+1,j}) = \sum_{i \ge 0} u_{i+1,j} z^{-i} = u_{1,j} +  u_{2,j}z^{-1} + u_{3,j}z^{-2} + ... =\\
=  z(   u_{1,j}z^{-1} +  u_{2,j}z^{-2} + u_{3,j}z^{-3} + ...)  = z(  \mathcal Z(u_{i,j})   -  u_{0,j} )$